# Universal Image Loader displayImage will not show image from SD card, but works with URL

Tags: android, android-imageview, universal-image-loader

I am trying to update Universal Image Loader within my Android app from 1.5.5 to 1.8.4 (latest version). However, with 1.8.4 images from the SD card do not load. URL's still work fine.

My code (works on 1.5.5):

```
imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(WallpaperDownload.this);
imageLoader.init(config);

DisplayImageOptions options1 = new     DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showStubImage(R.drawable.placeholder_large)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.placeholder_failed).cacheInMemory().cacheOnDisc().build();

String imageUri = "file:///mnt/sdcard/mm18/Wallpapers/Speedometer.jpg";
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri,wallpaperImgView, options1);
```

The images that this code is loading are about 800x600px so I wonder if this is causing issues with UIL? LogCat shows no problems.

I'd appreciate any help, I am new to Java so it might be obvious to somebody else!

Comment: do you get any errors.?

Comment: No, I receive no errors.

Comment: I was using universal image loader 1.7.0 for the same purpose and it works for me. I tried with the latest v1.8.4 and looks like many changes has been made. if i get a working solution, i will let u know.

Comment: check out the change log and try to make appropriate changes in the library functions.

Comment: I have gone over and over the change log and examples for past few days, fixing a few issues, but I can't seem to resolve this particular issue. I've tried various different configuration options etc but having no luck!

Comment: Can you try 1.8.2 version?

Comment: I seem to have resolved the problem. The developer of my app put imageLoader.stop() inside the onStop() of the previous activity which displays images user has downloaded in a GridView. Clicking a thumbnail launches the WallpaperDownload activity which loads UIL with different options and displays the image from SD card (or URL if user has not downloaded it). If I call UIL in a subsequent activity as in this case, should I be placing imageLoader.stop() somewhere? Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you go to the next Activity, `onStop()` of previous Activity isn't called. only `onPause()`.

Answer (score 2):

use link like

```
file:///sdcard/yourfolder
```

its work for me